# App to track positive activities to use as "currency" for relaxing activities

Tags: android

There are plenty of apps to track what you do throughout the day, but I'm looking for something a little more specific and if a good one doesn't already exist, I'll just try to make an AirTable or similar, which may not be as nice to use.

Basically, I'd like to mark things like "Finished big work project" or "Read a chapter of personal project book" or "Exercised for 30 minutes", assign them various point values that increase, and then "buy" myself things like watching a TV show.

For a healthier way of living I'd like to make doing things that don't really add value to my life as "expensive" that I have to earn, to help me get into better habits with them by "budgeting" my time, in the same way someone sensible with finances saves up to splash out on things, but wisely. Does such a system exist?

An Android app would be most ideal, but I'd consider web apps or others.